# Different values when calculating signal's energy by hand vs MATLAB

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals, signal-energy

Given the following signal:

$$
x(n) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      u(0.01n-0.025)2.3704e^{(-0.287682n)},   & n\ge 0 \\
      u(-(0.01n+0.025))2.3704e^{(0.287682n)}, & n< 0 \\
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

I'm finding the energy using the summation formula:

$$E_{x(n)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |x(n)|^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2.3704e^{(-0.287682n)}u(0.01n-0.025))^2+\sum_{n=-\infty}^0 (2.3704e^{(0.287682n)}u(-(0.01n+0.025)))^2 =\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2.3704e^{(-0.287682n)}u(0.01n-0.025))^2+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(2.3704e^{(-0.287682n)}u(-(0.01n+0.025)))^2 = 2\times2.3704^2\times \sum_{n=0}^\infty (e^{(-0.287682\times 2)}u(0.01n-0.025))^n$$

So due to the sampling frequency and other information given about the problem, the sampling doesn't start until $n=3$ so I adjusted the limits of summation and removed the u(n) function:

$$=2\times2.3704^2\times \sum_{n=3}^\infty (e^{(-0.287682\times 2)})^n$$

And then adjusted the series to begin at $n=1$ so I could use the summation formula:

$$=2\times2.3704^2\times(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{(-0.287682\times 2)})^n - (e^{(-0.287682\times 2)})^1 - (e^{(-0.287682\times 2)})^2)$$

So the series converges since the common ratio $<1$ and the sum of the series is:

$$S_{\infty}=\frac{a_1}{1-r}=\frac{(e^{(-0.287682\times 2)})^1}{1-e^{(-0.287682\times 2)}}=1.2857$$

Replacing the number above in the energy summation equation, I get:

$$E_{x(n)}=2\times 2.3704^2\times(1.2857-0.5625-0.3164)=4.5715$$

However, when I use MATLAB to find the energy of the signal using the following code:

```
E = 0
for i=1:fs+1
    E = E + abs(x(i))^2
end
```

where `fs` is the sampling frequency, the code yields the following result:

$$E=2.2858$$

which doesn't match my mathematical method. However, I noticed that the answer that MATLAB gives me is half the answer of what I got by hand. I also know with certainty that the MATLAB answer is correct.

So how do I go from $4.5715$ to $2.2858$? What's the step/reasoning that I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you calculate signal energy of `fs+1` points? Shouldn't it be as long as possible?

Comment: @ZRHan because x() is a vector and vectors start their indices at 1 rather than 0 in MATLAB; x() is also the time-index vector in terms of n where n includes 0 so the +1 in the ```fs+1``` line is to compensate for that

Comment: @ZRHan nvm, I just realized my error and what you mean. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don’t know rest of the given code, I’ve decided to calculate the energy other way round.

The MATLAB code for calculating the given function’s energy is given below:

```
syms n; % Symbol assignment for summation

Energy_1 = symsum(power((2.3704 * exp(0.287682 * n)), 2), n, -Inf, -3); % Energy for the left-hand side of the sample domain

Energy_2 = symsum(power((2.3704 * exp(-0.287682 * n)), 2), n, 3, Inf ); % Energy for the right-hand side of the sample domain

Energy = Energy_1 + Energy_2 % Overall energy
```

According to this code above, the resultant overall energy becomes $E = 4.5715$.

As the number of samples increases, the result gets accurate. Also, the coefficient in the exponential’s power affects the accuracy of the result too, but this is not the main case.

Comment: Ok I'm dumb I just figured out why; an issue with my code. The x(i) vector in my code contains the samples from -inf to +inf but i goes from 1 to half the samples, so it's only summing up half the samples, which obviously gives half the energy. I feel so stupid rn haha thank you for your help

Comment: @Kevin KZ That is okay, no problem.